# How to make a query using a database function with Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I want to query the database using a `WHERE` clause like this in Django ORM:

```
WHERE LOWER(col_name) = %s
```

or

```
WHERE LOWER(col_name) = LOWER(%s)
```

How can I do this using QuerySet API?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `__iexact` for case-insensitive comparison instead?

Comment: I have an index on `LOWER(col_name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extra` to add a custom where condition using sql functions:

```
Author.objects.extra(where=["lower(name) = lower(%s)"], params=['Fabio'])
```

You want to use params instead of embedding the value directly in the query to avoid SQL injection by letting Django escape the params for you.

If you can avoid using the sql `LOWER` function on the param you pass (in my example 'Fabio'), then you can use `annotate` instead:

```
Author.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('name')).filter(name_lower=your_name.lower())
```

Note that `your_name.lower()` is using the python `lower` function, not the sql one.

I couldn't find a way to use annotate together with `F()` or `Lower()` (`from django.db.models.functions import Lower`) to apply `Lower` to your custom input, as opposed to another field.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude `name_lower` from the fields in `SELECT` ?

Comment: @planetp what do you mean? If you use the ```extra``` example, there shouldn't be any additional fields added to the SELECT <fields> part of the query. Annotate would select the field though

Comment: Yep, `extra()` works for me. `annotate()` adds the fields to the `SELECT` list which is undesired (I only want to filter on the expression, not to select it).